# Efficiently keeping track of changes in text

Tags: python, performance, websocket, network-programming

I have to send some text over the network to another computer in python. I'll probably do this using sockets. I'm doing this so people on two different computers can edit a document at the same time. I was wondering whether there was an efficient way I could do this. I figure sending the updated text everytime a user presses a key doesn't make sense at all. Could I instead only send the changes that are made every time the user changes something in the text. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: take a look at meteor python.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to allow editing text to 2 (or more) clients, I would use a patch library such as diff_match_patch (google diff match patch).

Here is a sample code you can use :

```
import diff_match_patch as dmp

d = dmp()
patch = d.patch_make(current_text, new_text)
updated_text, status = d.patch_apply(patch, current_text)
```

So you can handle insertions, deletions and can even add undo operations...